# Issues in Logic app while passing JSON variable

Tags: json, replace, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, ssas-tabular

Requirement : I am trying to run SSAS tabular solution partition run based on tables and partitions through ADF and Logic App.
I have created one table with list of dimensions and fact tables present in tabular solution, trying to run some partitions passing it through ADF -> Logic App to process SSAS Solution automatically through Job.
But I am facing issue while reading the variable having JSON script.
How to remove \ from the string values?

[image]

I am expecting the removal of \ from my variable and pass it as JSON in Body.

Comment: The value of “objects” is actually a list of strings. You need to do more than just dealing with the slashes. You need to parse it as JSON.

Comment: Adding the parsing value . providing me error. 
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Initialize_variable_Formatted' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'json' expects its parameter to be a string or an XML. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#json for usage details.'.

Comment: Ok but what expression did you use that gave that error?

Comment: For reading JSON coming from ADF: 
Used Initialize Variable  Name: JSONBody, type: String, Value coming from ADF

Parse JSON: Using Data Operations:

Comment: Huh?  Your answer is below anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I got the expected results after I tried to convert the required variable `objects` into json. Below is something that I followed to achieve the results.

[image]

##### Results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
I am still getting this error while parsing the ADF values into Logic Apps.